# Hiding souce data Microsoft PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

I have situation that Excel file with powerquery have source from subfolders.

Unfortunately, in the csv and xls source files there are data in some column, that should not be shared. The program that generates this data, unfortunately, has no way not to generate it. These columns are not used in the report file by powerquery.

How can this data be hidden from users who should not have access to it? I cannot do it from the NTFS permission level because the user opening the file has to download the current data.

Answer (score 0):

If the source has data that cannot be shared, then you can't have the users connecting directly to the source data.

A workaround would be to set up an intermediate step that removes these columns and have the user connect to that instead.